# User Control losing properties on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control which has a number of properties. This user control is placed inside a TemplateField of a GridView, and the properties are databound from the grid's datasource. On the user control I have some LinkButton's which carry out actions, using some of the properties as properties (e.g. I pass in a row's ID)

The values go into it fine, but as soon as the LinkButton is clicked on the usercontrol, the properties reset to null so the LinkButton action doesn't work. What could cause this? I have made sure ViewState is enabled.

EDIT: Some code:

Properties:

```
public long? _InvoiceID;
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.Attribute)]
[Bindable(BindableSupport.Yes)]
public long? InvoiceID {get { return _InvoiceID; } set { _InvoiceID = value; } }
```

Comment: Only your code can tell the tale,try posting it

Comment: Common problem I have, I code on a machine with no Internet access so I can't copy and paste. I'll type some of it up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to save values you passed to user control into Hidden fields within your user control and when you click the `LinkButton` read the hidden field value

**Update**

the variable `long? _InvoiceID` is a stateless so you can try this

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.Attribute)]
[Bindable(BindableSupport.Yes)]
public long? InvoiceID 
{
   get { 
         return (long?)_InvoiceIDHiddenn.Value; 
       } 
   set {
          _InvoiceIDHiddenn.Value = value; 
       } 
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that, but I'd like to avoid additional controls on the user control if possible to avoid any redundant markup, as this will be on every GridView row

Comment: you are right but I am afraid there is another way. but if it is possible create that `LinkButton` outside the user control

Comment: I went with this option in the end and it now works great. The extra syntax doesn't have any performance impact so all's well :) many thanks